# MX Notify Control in EE v 2.10.1

Tags: mx-notify

Does anyone know if there is an issue with this plugin for v 2.10.1 of EE? I've installed the plugin, created a rule for Entry Added, but I'm not receiving any notifications. I don't receive an error or anything, but nothing happens. I feel like I'm missing something really simple as the plugin seems very straightforward. My goal is for the super admin to be notified when a new entry has been added because the entry is closed and they have to know so they can change the status to open. I'm using it to moderate content.

[image]

Comment: Have you tested sending email without MX Notify? In your Control Panel, when you go to `CP Home -> Tools -> Communicate` and send a test email (to a different domain hosted email address), do you receive it?

Comment: Yes, when I send an email via Communicate it comes through.